# How do I modify this python script to avoid a syntax error?

Tags: python

I am brand new to python and trying to use it for the first time. I have installed python 3.9.4 and am trying a super simple script:

```
python3 -m pip --version
```

But python is returning a syntax error. What am I doing wrong? The python terminal shows the following:

```
>>> python3 -m pip --version
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3 -m pip --version
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
support
```

Comment: What do you expect to achieve by such script?

Comment: to return the version on python I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to type that command in cli, not python shell. See image; the first command works, the second does not. It's not python code.
[image: cli output]